# Cohomology of sheaf extended by zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective scheme of pure dimension $1$. Let $U$ be a open subscheme and $j:U \to X$ the open immersion. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $U$.
Denote by $j_!(\mathcal{F})$ the extension of $\mathcal{F}$ by zero (as mentioned in Hartshorne, Algebraic geometry Ex. II.$1.19$). Is it true that $H^1(U,\mathcal{F})=H^1(X,j_!(\mathcal{F}))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is almost never true.

**Claim** Let $X$ be a separated one-dimensional scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field. Let $U\subseteq X$ be a dense open set that does not contain any irreducible component of $X$. Further let $\mathscr F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then

1. $H^1(U,\mathscr F|_U)=0$, and
2. $H^1(X,j_!(\mathscr F|_U))\twoheadrightarrow H^1(X,\mathscr F)$ is surjective.

In particular, if $H^1(X,\mathscr F)\neq 0$, then $H^1(U,\mathscr F|_U)\neq H^1(X,j_!(\mathscr F|_U))$

**Proof** The assumptions imply that

1. $U$ is affine, and
2. $Z=X\setminus U$ is zero-dimensional.

The above 1. implies 1. in the Claim and via the short exact sequence
$$
0\to j_!(\mathscr F|_U) \to \mathscr F \to j_*(\mathscr F|_Z) \to 0
$$

the above 2. implies 2. in the Claim. $\square$

Comment: do you perhaps want Z to also intersect every irreducible component of X?  (Otherwise it seems you could have U = X.)

Comment: Roy, you're right, thanks. I meant that, but neglected to write it there. Without that $U$ is not necessarily affine.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not true. This works for extensions from **closed** subsets. Take for $X$ an irrational curve, so that $H^1(X;\mathcal{O}_X)\ne0$, and let $U=X\setminus\text{point}$ and $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_U$, which is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_X$. You immediately get $H^1(X,j_!\mathcal{F})\twoheadrightarrow H^1(X;\mathcal{O}_X)$, whereas $H^1(U,\mathcal{F})=0$.